# Error al ejecutar Localdate

Tags: localdate

espero puedan ayudarme con mi problema que es el siguiente, programé un método que al colocar una fecha me arroja la fecha un mes después. Acá les mando el código:
private void fechaPasar() {
if (datos1.equals("1 MES")) {

```
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        var dateTime = LocalDate.parse(txt_desde.getText(), dateFormat);
        var newDateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(1);
        String resultado = newDateTime.format(dateFormat);
        txt_hasta.setText(resultado);

    }
```

}

Una vez que ejecuto el programa me arroja el siguiente error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/' could not be parsed at index 3
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/0' could not be parsed at index 3
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/03' could not be parsed at index 5
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/03/' could not be parsed at index 6
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/03/2' could not be parsed at index 6
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/03/20' could not be parsed at index 6
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/03/202' could not be parsed at index 6
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4509)
at ventanas.Cobertura2.txt_desdeKeyReleased(Cobertura2.java:2944)
at ventanas.Cobertura2$17.keyReleased(Cobertura2.java:578)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextComponent.processEvent(TextComponent.java:682)
at java.desktop/java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:631)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:870)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1139)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1009)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 15 seconds)

Desde ya les agradezco espero puedan ayudarme ya que intente de todo y no logro el resultado esperado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.